# callable as instancemethod?

Tags: python, methods, metaclass, python-descriptors

Let's say we've got a metaclass `CallableWrappingMeta` which walks the body of a new class, wrapping its methods with a class, `InstanceMethodWrapper`:

```
import types

class CallableWrappingMeta(type):
    def __new__(mcls, name, bases, cls_dict):
        for k, v in cls_dict.iteritems():
            if isinstance(v, types.FunctionType):
                cls_dict[k] = InstanceMethodWrapper(v)
        return type.__new__(mcls, name, bases, cls_dict)

class InstanceMethodWrapper(object):
    def __init__(self, method):
        self.method = method
    def __call__(self, *args, **kw):
        print "InstanceMethodWrapper.__call__( %s, *%r, **%r )" % (self, args, kw)
        return self.method(*args, **kw)

class Bar(object):
    __metaclass__ = CallableWrappingMeta
    def __init__(self):
        print 'bar!'
```

Our dummy wrapper just prints the arguments as they come in. But you'll notice something conspicuous: the method isn't passed the instance-object receiver, because even though `InstanceMethodWrapper` is callable, it is not treated as a function for the purpose of being converted to an instance method during class creation (after our metaclass is done with it).

A potential solution is to use a decorator instead of a class to wrap the methods -- that function will become an instance method. But in the real world, `InstanceMethodWrapper` is much more complex: it provides an API and publishes method-call events. A class is more convenient (and more performant, not that this matters much).

I also tried some dead-ends. Subclassing `types.MethodType` and `types.UnboundMethodType` didn't go anywhere. A little introspection, and it appears they decend from `type`. So I tried using both as a metaclass, but no luck there either. It might be the case that they have special demands as a metaclass, but it seems we're in undocumented territory at this point.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you please explain more? I am having trouble understanding what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just enrich you `InstanceMethodWrapper` class with a `__get__` (which can perfectly well just `return self`) -- that is, make that class into a *descriptor* type, so that its instances are descriptor objects.  See http://users.rcn.com/python/download/Descriptor.htm for background and details.

BTW, if you're on Python 2.6 or better, consider using a class-decorator instead of that metaclass -- we added class decorators exactly because so many metaclasses were being used just for such decoration purposes, and decorators are really much simpler to use.

Comment: This link is now dead (the answer is 10 years old!). Here's a good reference: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**: I lie yet again. The `__?attr__` attributes on functions are readonly, but apparently do not always throw an `AttributeException` exception when you assign? I dunno. Back to square one!

**Edit**: This doesn't actually solve the problem, as the wrapping function won't proxy attribute requests to the `InstanceMethodWrapper`. I could, of course, duck-punch the `__?attr__` attributes in the decorator--and it is what I'm doing now--but that's ugly. Better ideas are very welcome.

---

Of course, I immediately realized that combining a simple decorator with our classes will do the trick:

```
def methodize(method, callable):
    "Circumvents the fact that callables are not converted to instance methods."
    @wraps(method)
    def wrapper(*args, **kw):
        return wrapper._callable(*args, **kw)
    wrapper._callable = callable
    return wrapper
```

Then you add the decorator to the call to `InstanceMethodWrapper` in the metaclass:

```
cls_dict[k] = methodize(v, InstanceMethodWrapper(v))
```

Poof. A little oblique, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you are trying to make a metaclass that wraps every method in the class with a custom function.

Here is my version which I think is a little bit less oblique.

```
import types

class CallableWrappingMeta(type):
    def __new__(mcls, name, bases, cls_dict):
        instance = type.__new__(mcls, name, bases, cls_dict)
        for k in dir(instance):
            v = getattr(instance, k)
            if isinstance(v, types.MethodType):
                setattr(instance, k, instanceMethodWrapper(v))

        return instance

def instanceMethodWrapper(function):
    def customfunc(*args, **kw):
        print "instanceMethodWrapper(*%r, **%r )" % (args, kw)
        return function(*args, **kw)
    return customfunc

class Bar(object):
    __metaclass__ = CallableWrappingMeta

    def method(self, a, b):
        print a,b

a = Bar()
a.method("foo","bar")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to be more specific about your problem.  The original question talks about wrapping a function, but your subsequent answer seems to talk about preserving function attributes, which seems to be a new factor.  If you spelled out your design goals more clearly, it might be easier to answer your question.